# How to sort in mongoose by multiple fields?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have this schema and it has two fields

```
someDate: Date
isPriority: boolean
```

and I want to make a sort query by `someDate` **and** records with `isPriority: true` should be always first.
So how should it look like? Right now I know how to sort by date like this:

```
Record.find().sort({ someDate: -1 });
```

Comment: I think it's just the key order... so `{isPriority:1,someDate:-1}`. The wrong way, meaning, would be `{someDate:-1,isPriority:1}`

Comment: oh okay, I didn't know that's so simple, I will try it tomorrow thanks

Comment: @CodyＧ  You should make that an answer.  I don't see any other questions on SO yet that ask how to sort by multiple fields, you could be the first.

Answer (score 1):

I think at some point MongoDB started supporting sort (by means of other than which index(s) it uses), and the key order works to support sorts.

Per [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/), to achieve a "stable" sort, ensure that you have a unique column as the last key.

```js
db.restaurants.find().sort( { "borough": 1, "_id": 1 } )
```

So, for your particular query, use:

```js
{isPriority: 1, someDate: -1, _id: 1}.
```

The wrong way, meaning, would be

```js
{someDate: -1, isPriority: 1, _id: 1}
```